# Trying to do setters and getters in dart using the get keyword

Tags: dart

I am writing this class, and noticed the anon function design you can use for small things.

```
String get fullName => "$fname $lname";   //A
```

and I got thinking on whether i should do my setters and getters in this fashion or the standard:

```
void setFullName( String fn, String ln ) {   //B
  fname = fn; 
  lname = ln; 
}

String getFullName(){   //C
  return "$fname $lname"; 
}
```

I know that the difference between `A` and `C` is that one is a method while the other is not.

```
print(fullName);
// vs
print(getFullName());
```

So, which approach is best.  I was reading a demo that said anon functions should really only be used when the function has reason to change.  I personally think that getters should be functions in teh traditional sense, but some things are pretty simple to just do shorthand.

If there is a shorthand for a getter like how i wrote `A`, is there a shorthand for a setter?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First in Dart fields are automatically wrapped by getters and setters. If you use reflection (mirrors) to query the members of a class, you'll get getters and setters instead of fields.
This is also reflected in the Dart style guide:

> Don't wrap fields with getters/setters just to be sure.

You can change fields to getters/setters any time without breaking code that uses your class.

Other things to consider for getters/setters are: they shouldn't do expensive computation and they shouldn't have side-effects (except of setting the backing field when calling the setter).

If these criteria are met (and you don't need additional parameters), then it's usually a good idea to use getters/setters.

Note: short-hand function notation is not limited to getters/setters and they also don't require it. You can use it for functions as well and you can have block bodies for getters/setters as well.

```
bool _isSet;
bool get isSet {
  return _isSet;
}
set isSet(bool value) {
  if(value is null) {
    throw new ArgumentError();
  }
  _isSet = value;
}
```

and you use them like

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.isSet = true; // setter
print(myClass.isSet); // getter
```

Comment: Great to know. So natively, in my sample: fname automatically has a getter and a setter?  So if i wanted to access them outside the scope of the class by a function call i could say what?     `Class Person{}  Person p = new Person();   p.fname(name);` or what?  Im not a fan of exposing variables such as:   `p.fname = name;`

Comment: I did notice while using Dartpad that even though it is assigned as a variable, it is publicly accessible from the class for assignments.

is there a way to make them private or protected?

Comment: I know based on information, it says `_` is to be used to denote private variables.... though they arent *really* private now, are they.

Comment: Oh found it in stack overflow.  Thanks.  Ill link it here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488611/how-in-dart-create-private-variable

Comment: I updated my answer. In Dart you make fields, getter/setters and functions/methods private by starting the name with an underscore (`_`). You read and  set getter/setters the same as fields (see my update).

Comment: Thank you! :)  Very Helpful.  Its just weird a bit.  Used to Setters and Getters being functions in a traditional sense. heh.  No Paren's required for this.  Alright

Comment: Such properties are quite common in a variety of programming languages. I knew them from C# for example.

Answer (score 5):

unnecessary_getters_setters

From the style guide:

AVOID wrapping fields in getters and setters just to be "safe".

In Java and C#, it's common to hide all fields behind getters and setters (or properties in C#), even if the implementation just forwards to the field. That way, if you ever need to do more work in those members, you can without needing to touch the callsites. This is because calling a getter method is different than accessing a field in Java, and accessing a property isn't binary-compatible with accessing a raw field in C#.

Dart doesn't have this limitation. Fields and getters/setters are completely indistinguishable. You can expose a field in a class and later wrap it in a getter and setter without having to touch any code that uses that field.

[image]