# How private variable/property and method works?

Tags: dart, flutter

As far I been to doc's and tutorials I got to know we need to use `underscore` to define properties or methods but from by below code I can still access it.

```
void main() {
  User d = new User('John Doe', 5);
  print(d._name);
}

class User {
  String _name;
  int age;

  User(this._name, this.age);

  String respectedName(nname) {
    return 'Mr.$nname';
  }
}
```

I am not sure that I understand how things works in Dart, please help.

There is smiler question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488611/how-in-dart-create-private-variable), but that's still not much of a helpful answer to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private properties/methods in dart are accessible for the whole file and not accessible from other files.

This can be combined with `part`/`part of` keyword to treat two+ files as one.

Comment: accessible for the whole library, which is typically just a file.