# What does Underscore "_" before variable name mean for Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

with reference to the [Flutter](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2/#3) tutorial, I encountered an underscore, `_`.

I know that in Java, `_` is used as a naming convention for a private variable.

1. Does it also apply to Flutter? Noting that there is no public/protected in Flutter.
2. Will the `_` really be private (inaccessible by other classes) or is it just a naming convention?

#### Variable

```dart
class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  final List<WordPair> _suggestions = <WordPair>[];
  final Set<WordPair> _saved = new Set<WordPair>();
  final TextStyle _biggerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);
  ...
}
```

3. Does the `_` make the Widget private too? In this case, wouldn't the main class be unable to assess the Widget?

#### Function

```dart
Widget _buildRow(WordPair pair) {
  final bool alreadySaved = _saved.contains(pair);  // Add this line.
  ...
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53022431/10269042

Comment: @GeorgiyChebotarev Well, there are three groups of programmer: `Static-Typers`, `Dynamic-Typers` and `NoMatter-Typers`. Those who love using types and keywords, and those who just want to dump out "pseudo" code, and others who do not care.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

It's **not** just a naming convention. Underscore fields, classes and methods will only be available in the `.dart` file where they are defined.

It is common practice to make the `State` implementation of a widget private, so that it can only be instantiated by the corresponding `StatefulWidget`:

```
class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 101):

From the [Dart guide](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility)

> Unlike Java, Dart doesn’t have the keywords public, protected, and
>   private. If an identifier starts with an underscore (_), it’s private
>   to its library. For details, see [Libraries and visibility](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility).

Answer (score 3):

Private fields also have the advantage that Lint can identify which fields were declared/instantiated and not used, which helps identify human errors.

If you declare a public field, the field may be accessed by classes outside the class in the future and so Lint cannot warn you if you added the field by mistake.