# Instance members can't be accessed from a static method

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the code:

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  User? _user;
  final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods();

  static User get getUser => **_user!;**

  Future<void> refreshUser() async {
    User user = await _authMethods.getUserDetails();
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I tried to call User but It had to be static so I made it static but now I have an issue with the _user!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `_user` as static field, and it will be accessible on static getter.

```dart
  static int? _user;

  static int get getUser => _user!;
```

Answer (score 1):

With prefix _ (underscore) it makes the member `_user` private, dart doesn't have private/public keywords.

In your case, in order to access the `_user` you can create a getter to access it.

You can also check the [Libraries & Visibility](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility) section of dartlang.

Check more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53142242)