# Flutter - How to access a function inside a statefulwidget in a file and then use it in a separate file with another stateful class?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use a function that is defined in file no:1 into file no:2.  I have imported the file 1 in file 2 and want to use some functions that is defined inside the class of file 1. I can access the class itself but not the variables and functions. I want to use those functions in an onpressed but can't.

**CODE of FILE 1**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';


class TimeDisplay extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TimeDisplayState createState() => _TimeDisplayState();
}

class _TimeDisplayState extends State<TimeDisplay> {
  Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch();
  Timer timer;

  String elapsedTime= '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
            child: Text(
              elapsedTime,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 80.0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          );
  }
    startWatch(){
    watch.start();
    setTime();
  }

  stopWatch(){
    watch.stop();
    setTime();
  }

  resetWatch(){
    watch.reset();
    setTime();
  }

  setTime(){
    var timeSoFar = watch.elapsedMilliseconds;
    setState(() {
          elapsedTime = transformMilliseconds(timeSoFar);
        }); 
  }

  transformMilliseconds(int milliseconds) {
    int hundreds =(milliseconds / 10).truncate();
    int seconds =(hundreds / 100).truncate();
    int minutes =(seconds / 60).truncate();

    String minutesStr = (minutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    String secondsStr = (seconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    String hundredsStr = (hundreds % 100).toString().padLeft(2, '0');

    return "$minutesStr:$secondsStr";
  }
}
```

**CODE of FILE 2**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:getfit/timedisplay.dart';
import 'dart:async';





class ChangingBtn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChangingBtnState createState() => _ChangingBtnState();
}

class _ChangingBtnState extends State<ChangingBtn> {
    bool playing = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TimeDisplay(),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, bottom: 100.0),
          child: RawMaterialButton(
            shape: CircleBorder(),
            fillColor: Colors.red,
            splashColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
            highlightColor: Colors.orangeAccent.withOpacity(0.5),
            elevation: 10.0,
            highlightElevation: 5.0,
            onPressed: () {

              setState(() {
               playing = !playing;
               });
               playing ?  startWatch
               : stopWatch;
            },

            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),

              child: Icon(
               playing ?  Icons.pause
               : Icons.play_arrow,

                color: Colors.white,
                size: 35.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

}
```

I think I am doing something wrong here, I am not sure

```
onPressed: () {

              setState(() {
               playing = !playing;
               });
               playing ?  startWatch
               : stopWatch;
            },
```

If anyone could explain it I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Use global state management

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488611/how-to-create-private-variables-in-dart

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create private variables in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488611/how-to-create-private-variables-in-dart)

Comment: Thanks Oswin . That example really helped

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function inside that class and it can be accessed once the class has been initialized.

For example

```dart
main(){
  var foo = Foo();
  print('${foo.bar()}');  // Prints 'Hello'
}

class Foo{
  bar(){
    return 'Hello';
  }
}
```