# Create Class with a async

Tags: dart, flutter

im new on the flutter and curious how class and async work.
for example, i have function.dart file and inside function.dart file, i create method that i can call in other dart file.

but i found a difficult. i created a class with async inside, detail code below :

```
class updateItem {
  // do something

  Future<List> _SelectTableNumber() async {
    sql code
  }
{
```

when i try call class `updateItem` on other dart file and found _SelectTableNumber not running and i double check the system said _SelectTableNumber() method isn't used.

how do i run the _SelectTableNumber() inside my class updateItem?

Comment: show the code where you call `_SelectTableNumber()` method

Comment: here the class code :
class SelectTableNumber{
  Future<List> _SelectTableNumber() async{
    final response = await http.get(BaseUrl.SelectTableNumber);
    var datauser = json.decode(response.body);
    print("Data Kosong");

    if (datauser.length == 0) {

        print("Data Kosong");

    } else {
      global.strtransnomor = datauser[0]['Nomor'];
      int count1 = 1;
      //print(global.strtransnomor+1);
    }
  }


}

Comment: here the code i call my class :

FlatButton(
                child: Text('Cancel'),
                onPressed: (){
                  print('a');
                  function.SelectTableNumber;
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                }
              )

Comment: Please post the code on original post and format code.

Answer (score 0):

Your method name begins with an underscore `_` and that means the method is declared as private. Private methods can only be called from inside the library, NOT from another library.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488611/how-to-create-private-variables-in-dart).

Also please read the [basic docs about async](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures).

Comment: when i delete the _ my code error with red underline on:
Future<List> SelectTableNumber() async{

}

what should i change to make it right?

Comment: After seeing your code in the comment - Give the method a different name from the class name, otherwise it is being interpreted as a constructor, which it is not.

Comment: sorry my bad. yes sure i change it already. i try call the class again but seem not working. the Future<void> TableNumber() async{ } still not running, any advice?

Comment: You cannot call a class. Try calling the method instead. A future has to be called like this: `myobj.SelectTableNumber().then((List futureReturnValue){ //do something with list });`

Comment: OMG!! IT WORK!!! thank you so much!! you save my lifee!!
i really appreciated it!!!