# How do I properly (idiomatically) do private members in dart?

Tags: oop, dart

I am just starting to learn the dart programming language.

Something that I have stumbled on, is the less conventional way of doing access modifiers such as public / private (at least compared to my experience with C# , Java, and C++).

As I understand it, prefixing your member variables with with _ character, will make the private to that lib (file).

So is it common practice to just enforce a single class to a single file/lib, to enforce a behaviour similar to class level public/private?

Will that also result in all descendants of a class having to be in the same class.

If this is not common practice, how exactly do you do OOP in dart? How do you implement OOP concepts like encapsulation and composition in dart?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "class private" in Dart, only "library private".

The underlying design is based on the idea that a single library is one entity, created and edited by the same people with the same goals. You should not need to defend yourself against your co-authors. After all, if you try to hide something from a co-author, they can just change your class to make it public anyway. So, a full library is the granularity of access management.

It is easy to make multiple small libraries, so you can make a library contain only things that are actually related. If you do that, then, again, you shouldn't need to prevent access between the objects, because they should be designed together, so the access is probably intended.

A library is also the granularity of *implementation*. A library exposes its public interfaces, but the implementation details are (library) private, so changing implementation details should not break other libraries. That makes it safe to change the implementation; as long as you only change private things, you are guranteed that no other library will break.

That is, private members can be seen as *implementation details*. If you need to access the implementation of another class, not just its public interface, then you are deeply interdependent on that implementation, and the code deserves to be in the same library.

Libraries with few related and interdependent classes, and sometimes a single class, is the way to go, and what people usually do. 
If you then want your package library to expose a lot of classes, you can export those individual libraries.

As for descendants of a class: Dart does not have *protected* access restriction, so if a subclass needs access to something, it needs to either be public, or be in the same file. There are tricky workarounds, but it's usually simpler go for one of those two. Again, if another class needs access to something that is not public, then it *is* related to the *implementation*, and should be kept close to that implementation.

Encapsulation means preventing access to implementation details. You do that at the library level. Inside the library, it's your own responsibility to only do things you intend to do. Composition works like in any other OO language.

Answer (score -1):

From Dart documentation:

```
Unlike Java, Dart doesn’t have the keywords public, protected, and private. 
If an identifier starts with an underscore _, it’s private to its library.
```

Libraries not only provide APIs, but are a unit of privacy: identifiers that start with an underscore _ are visible only inside the library.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17488825/7068790) may help you.

Comment: Your answer restated what was already in the initial question, and did not adress the question. -1.