# Flutter : How to setText from Sharedpreference data?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-layout

I've a small question for you all, I want to showing data from sharepref variable to UI Widget. I just now learn flutter and still confused.

this is my sharedpref to read data.

```
void loginStatus() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String user = prefs.getString('username');
    String pasw = prefs.getString('password');
  }
```

and I want to "user" is set in UI widget `Text($user)`, I hope you guys can give some reference or some code to me, thanks guys for your reason and I hope you well in this condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your var at top of the class to make them accessible in the class

```
String user='';
```

then call your loginStatus in `initState()`

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  loginStatus(); 
}
```

then append your `loginstatus` as follows

```
void loginStatus() async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState()({
    user = prefs.getString('username');
    pasw = prefs.getString('password');
  }); 
}
```

now you can use Text("$user") anywhere.

Comment: This is a good answer but there's one thing here that could break the code. Never ever call setState() in initState()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is but you need to scope your variables better.
declare `String user` and `String pasw` outside of the method. I assume they are private fields so rename them to `_user` and `_pasw`. The underscore makes them private in dart.

then:

```
void loginStatus() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() => {
       user = prefs.getString('username');
       pasw = prefs.getString('password');
     })
  }
```

Comment: This answer doesn't respond to the OP's question. This should be a comment. Also, it's not exactly correct, as you can confirm in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17488813/1003059